# Phase and amplitude in a periodic process

Tags: time-series, self-study, normal-distribution

I am currently working out of Time Series Analysis and its Applications (R. H. Shumway & D. S. Stoffer 2ed) and am stuck of something that is said.

The books says that if we have some periodic process:

$$x_t=Acos(2\pi wt + \phi)$$

where $A$ and $\phi$ vary randomly, we can write this as:

$$x_t=U_1cos(2\pi wt) + U_2sin(2\pi wt)$$

where
$$U_1=Acos\phi \enspace \enspace U_2=-Asin(\phi)$$

This I understand, as it is using a trig identity. However, the book continues and says that if we assume $U_1$ and $U_2$ are normally distributed, then we have:
$$A=\sqrt{U_1^2+U_2^2}$$
$$\phi = tan^{-1}(-U_2/U_1)$$

I understand how we can arrive at these mathematically, as they are fairly straightforward calculations, but what I don't understand is why $U_1$ and $U_2$ are required to be normally distributed.

I feel like the normal distribution being closed under linear operations may have something to do with it, but this would just lead to $A$ and $\phi$ being normally distributed, which isn't the point.

Comment: There is no distributional requirement to perform any of these calculations.  The point to assuming Normality is that it implies $A$ has an Exponential distribution and $\phi$ has a uniform distribution.

Comment: Do you think the textbook is just unclear?

Comment: I cannot form any opinion about that without seeing exactly what the textbook states.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look?